# How to detect if a pointer referenced by a TThreadList is invalid to avoid AV

Tags: delphi, sockets, pointers, threadpool

I have a `TThreadList` wich holds all pointers to objects created by my server. The server has a pool of threads to send data to all clients in that thread list. It locks the list and then releases the list after a user disconnects, removing the object and reference pointer.

Problem is: with the pool of threads that does not know when a socket is disconnected and deleted, so when the pool works, it will AV on selected pointer from the thread list that is somehow already deleted.

Example, pool's `Execute` method:

```
  try
    with userlist.LockList do 
    begin
      for i := Count - 1 downto 0 do
      begin
        if i >= 0 then 
        begin
          p := TClient(items[i]);
          //problem here p gets deleted so it raises items[i] 
          //have an invalid pointer to memory
          if p <> nil then
            if p.sockethex <> nil then
            begin
              sendtexthexpool(p.sockethex, msgprimit+ '|'); //here AV cause P was deleted
            end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    userlist.UnlockList;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. First, your if is superfluous. Second, how a item of the list can be _deleted_ if the list is locked? Any other list working with this data must wait until the list is unlocked. It happens automatically by locking it before doing anything. But maybe you don't need to lock all the list to avoid performance problems, you have to find a mechanism to lock only the item you're interested in, so you know it will not be changed during the time you need that pointer to be valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you have is a pointer, there's no way for you to tell whether or not it has been freed. You have to get your program to keep track of this information.

Even if you could detect a stale pointer, which you can't, it would not help you. You would still have a race.

In your excerpt you have a thread list. So long as all access to the pointer is made whilst the list is locked then you will have no problems. Presumably you are freeing the object whilst not holding a lock to the list. Fix that problem and all should be well.

Comment: the tclient reference gets deleted but the problem with locklist is both threads dont know about each other .one takes the list and deletes p and the other form pool wich is somehow delayed has a copy of old userlist wich has invalid references to memory so AV occurres

Comment: Like I said, you need to fix that. You can't have two threads holding references to the same object and let one of them destroy the object without synchronisation.

Comment: The thread that deletes `p` also needs to set `p` to `nil` (after synchronizing, as David says), and then your `if p <> nil` will work as it should.

Comment: also should i avoid locking to much inside threads not to affect overall performance.I tried to get the function out of the poolthreads and worked without problems but the cpu usage was to high on server under alot of stress testing clients.

Comment: Obviously you want to avoid locking if you can. But you need your program to be correct.

Comment: The problem was p.free on disconnecting socket ..so the pool was trying to execute an nonexistent object reference..I did found a solution to free the object inside pool after setting only nil on disconnect,now it works almost correctly.Thanks for help